# Detecting PROCESS_TEXT intent with React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

I am working with Expo (SDK 42) and am attempting to wire up the PROCESS_TEXT intent so that other apps, specifically browsers can pass the selected text to my app. After some steps, below, the intent is working but I can't figure out how to detect which intent was sent or how to get the text that's passed with the intent.

Here's what I have done. Note that I'm using a bare workflow, just a pre-build without code modifications at this point.

**I Added The Intent Filter**

In app.json, I added this under the "android" key:

```json
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "PROCESS_TEXT",
          "data": {
            "mimeType": "text/plain"
          },
          "category": [
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ],
```

and confirmed it added this to the manifest:

```xml
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

After installing this version, the browser shows an option on the menu when text is selected. It shows my main activity's name as a target for sharing the selected text. However, when I choose that option, the app launches a large warning comes up indicating that the Linking configuration was set up in multiple places. Not true. Linking was configured in exactly one place and so...

**I Removed the Linking Configuration**

This got rid of the warning and now when I choose the menu option, it gracefully launches the app, right from the beginning. How do I detect what Intent was used to launch the app and get the data the comes with it?

I've avoided adding native code to the app up to this point, but if I must I will do so. I assume that even if I get Linking working it isn't going to help identify the intent that launched the app. Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm stuck in the same problem looking for a solution.

Comment: How have you done linking configuration before?

Comment: I was never able to get this working. The project was put on the shelf, so maybe later versions of Expo have a way to do this.

Comment: @FitterMan couldn't get this working with Expo. Had to move to react native cli. Check this out a friend of mine helped me fix this problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74511279/5452620